# Как посчитать посты в категории?

Tags: php, sql

Доброе утро

Не удаётся корректно посчитать количество постов в категории. Вот такой счётчик:

```
public function pagesCount()
{
    return $this->db->col('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM pages WHERE :category');
}
```

Количество самих постов выводится верно, но пагинатор использует результат счётчика, который считает все посты в таблице и по этому выводит ссылки на все страницы, вот так (1 2 3 4 5 ... 8):

```
$pagination = new Pagination($this->route, $this->model->pagesCount(), 5);
```

Как-то нужно передать в счётчик id текущей категории для проверки соответствия со строками и правильного счёта.

Посты выводит вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM pages, categories ON categories.id = pages.category WHERE pages.category = :id LIMIT :start, :max' $params
```

Никак не могу сообразить.

Вот такой запрос в счётчике возвращает 1:

```
SELECT pages.category, COUNT(*) FROM categories JOIN pages ON pages.category = categories.id
```

Класс Pagination:

```
class Pagination
{

    private $max = INF;
    private $route;
    private $index = '';
    private $current_page;
    private $total;
    private $limit;

    public function __construct($route, $total, $limit = 5)
    {
        $this->route = $route;
        $this->total = $total;
        $this->limit = $limit;
        $this->amount = $this->amount();
        $this->setCurrentPage();
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $links = null;
        $limits = $this->limits();
        $html = '<ul>';
        for ($this->amount = null, $page = $limits[0]; $page <= $limits[1]; $page++) {
            if ($page == $limits[0] or $page == $limits[1] or abs($page - $this->current_page) < 3) { // 3
                if ($page == $this->current_page) {
                     $links .= $this->amount = '<li>' . $page . '</li>';
                } else {
                     $links .= $this->amount = $this->generateHtml($page);
                }
            } else {
                if ($this->amount == '<li>...</li>' or $this->amount == null) {
                     $links .= $this->amount = null;
                } else {
                     $links .= $this->amount = '<li>...</li>';
                }
            }
        }
        $html .= $links . '</ul>';
        return $html;
    }

    private function generateHtml($page, $text = null)
    {
        if (!$text) {
            $text = $page;
        }
        if ($this->route['action'] == 'category') {
            return '<li><a href="/' . $this->route['controller'] . '/' . $this->route['action'] . '/' . $this->route['id'] . '/' . $page . '">' . $text . '</a></li>';
        }
        return '<li><a href="/' . $this->route['controller'] . '/' . $this->route['action'] . '/' . $page . '">' . $text . '</a></li>';
    }

    private function limits()
    {
        $left = $this->current_page - round($this->max / 2);
        $start = $left > 0 ? $left : 1;
        if ($start + $this->max <= $this->amount) {
             $end = $start > 1 ? $start + $this->max : $this->max;
        } else {
             $end = $this->amount;
             $start = $this->amount - $this->max > 0 ? $this->amount - $this->max : 1;
        }
        return array($start, $end);
    }

    private function setCurrentPage()
    {
         if (isset($this->route['page'])) {
             $currentPage = $this->route['page'];
         } else {
             $currentPage = 1;
         }
         $this->current_page = $currentPage;
         if ($this->current_page > 0) {
             if ($this->current_page > $this->amount) {
                 $this->current_page = $this->amount;
             }
         } else {
             $this->current_page = 1;
         }
     }

     private function amount()
     {
         return ceil($this->total / $this->limit);
     }

 }
```

Пример вывода списка постов

1. Контроллер:

   public function pagesAction()
   {
   $pagination = new Pagination($this->route, $this->model->pagesCount(), 20);
   $vars = [
   'pagination' => $pagination->get(),
   'count' => $this->model->pagesCount(),
   'list' => $this->model->pagesList($this->route),
   ];
   $this->view->render('Список страниц', 0, 0, $vars);
   }
2. Счётчик:

   public function pagesCount()
   {
   return $this->db->col('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages');
   }
3. Модель:

   public function pagesList($route)
   {
   $max = 5;
   $params = [
   'max' => $max,
   'start' => (($route['page'] ?? 1) - 1) * $max,
   ];
   return $this->db->all('SELECT * FROM `pages` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :start, :max', $params);
   }

Прошу прощения, форматирование почему-то не установилось для последнего фрагмента.

Comment: `SELECT pages.category, COUNT(*) FROM pages GROUP BY category` можно подсчитать сразу во всех

Comment: @ArchDemon а зачем? :)

Comment: Ну вот же вы сами прикладываете код, "Пример вывода постов" и в нем такая строка: `public function pagesCount() { return $this->db->col('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages'); }`, посмотрите более детально на запрос: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages`. Не думаете, что условие забыли в этом случае? (выбираете абсолютно по всем категориям)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
public function pagesCount($id)
{
    $params = [
        'id' => $id,
    ];
    return $this->db->col('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM pages WHERE category = :id', $params);
}
```

В контроллере корректив:

```
$pagination = new Pagination($this->route, $this->model->pagesCount($this->route['id']), 5);
```

Теперь считает грамотно. Он теперь получает id категории и по этому возвращает точное количество по условию. Всем спасибо за внимание :)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ ваш кроется тут:

> Количество самих постов выводится верно, но пагинатор использует
> результат счётчика, который считает все посты в таблице

Т.е. у вас метод `pagesCount` отрабатывает верно и считает нормально, а не работает то `paginator`. Ваша задача, **не** написать какой-то эдакий запрос, а заставить `paginator` использовать результат вашего счетчика.

Т.к. зачастую (вы не указали, что это за paginator, какой фреймворк и т.д.) пагинатору отдается sqlQuery, текущая страница и кол-во элементов на ней, а пагинатор в свою очередь смотрит, что за таблица и строит запрос на общее кол-во в ней элементов (хотя и должен сохранить условия, чтобы корректно узнать total).

Если ответ не будет вам полезен, приложите больше данных о фреймворке или paginator-e (можете показать его исходный код).

Comment: Здравствуйте. Это самопис, я уже не помню где его нашёл, модифицировал за пару лет. Класс пагинатор особенно :), но он всё нормально считает для других целей. Например — списки файлов, просто постов и пр. Код его приложу в дополнении и пример для вывода списка постов.

Comment: Кстати, в правильном выводе статей `pagesCount` не участвует, в контроллере он вызывается только для того, чтобы пагинатор вывел корректное количество ссылок.